# Why is PHP's memory usage drastically differing in another environment, with the same code

Tags: php, memory, php-5.6

While debugging issues with a PHP script running into its `memory_limit`, I noticed that the exact same code increases memory usage in an Amazon Web Service environment, while staying consistent in my localhost. While there are differences in these environments, I would not expect such a large difference memory usage between the environments. Any insight would be appreciated.

#### AWS Environment

- OS: CentOS
- PHP: 5.6.36
- MySQL: 5.7.21-log
- PHP Extensions:

  [PHP Modules]
  bcmath
  bz2
  calendar
  Core
  ctype
  curl
  date
  dom
  ereg
  exif
  fileinfo
  filter
  ftp
  gd
  gettext
  hash
  iconv
  igbinary
  intl
  json
  libxml
  mbstring
  mcrypt
  memcached
  mhash
  mysql
  mysqli
  mysqlnd
  openssl
  pcntl
  pcre
  PDO
  pdo_mysql
  pdo_sqlite
  Phar
  posix
  readline
  Reflection
  session
  shmop
  SimpleXML
  soap
  sockets
  SPL
  sqlite3
  standard
  sysvmsg
  sysvsem
  sysvshm
  tokenizer
  wddx
  xml
  xmlreader
  xmlwriter
  xsl
  Zend OPcache
  zip
  zlib

  [Zend Modules]
  Zend OPcache

#### Localhost:

- OS: macOS High Sierra
- PHP: 5.6.35
- MariaDB: 10.1.31-MariaDB Source distribution
- PHP Extensions:

  [PHP Modules]
  bcmath
  bz2
  calendar
  Core
  ctype
  curl
  date
  dba
  dom
  ereg
  exif
  fileinfo
  filter
  ftp
  gd
  gettext
  hash
  iconv
  imap
  intl
  json
  ldap
  libxml
  mbstring
  mcrypt
  memcached
  mhash
  mysql
  mysqli
  mysqlnd
  openssl
  pcntl
  pcre
  PDO
  pdo_mysql
  pdo_pgsql
  pdo_sqlite
  Phar
  posix
  Reflection
  session
  shmop
  SimpleXML
  soap
  sockets
  SPL
  sqlite3
  standard
  sybase_ct
  sysvsem
  sysvshm
  tokenizer
  wddx
  xml
  xmlreader
  xmlrpc
  xmlwriter
  xsl
  zip
  zlib

#### Source Code In Question:

```
for ($i = 0, $j = count($data); $i < $j; $i += self::INSERT_CHUNK_SIZE) {
    $this->logMemory('INSERT CHUNK '.$i);
    $adapter->insertArray(
        $this->getIntermediateTableName(),
        array_merge($this->getFields(), ['file_ds']),
        array_slice($data, $i, self::INSERT_CHUNK_SIZE)
    );
}
```

- `$adapter` is an instance of `Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql` (for those unfamiliar with Magento, this class is an instance of `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql`)
- The contents of `$data` is identical both in localhost and in AWS.

#### AWS Logs:

```
Memory Usage: 212.69MB INSERT CHUNK 0
Memory Usage: 218.41MB INSERT CHUNK 7500
Memory Usage: 224.13MB INSERT CHUNK 15000
Memory Usage: 229.86MB INSERT CHUNK 22500
Memory Usage: 235.58MB INSERT CHUNK 30000
Memory Usage: 241.3MB INSERT CHUNK 37500
Memory Usage: 247.02MB INSERT CHUNK 45000
Memory Usage: 252.75MB INSERT CHUNK 52500
Memory Usage: 258.47MB INSERT CHUNK 60000
Memory Usage: 264.19MB INSERT CHUNK 67500
Memory Usage: 269.91MB INSERT CHUNK 75000
Memory Usage: 275.63MB INSERT CHUNK 82500
Memory Usage: 281.36MB INSERT CHUNK 90000
Memory Usage: 287.08MB INSERT CHUNK 97500
Memory Usage: 292.8MB INSERT CHUNK 105000
Memory Usage: 298.52MB INSERT CHUNK 112500
Memory Usage: 304.25MB INSERT CHUNK 120000
Memory Usage: 309.97MB INSERT CHUNK 127500
Memory Usage: 315.69MB INSERT CHUNK 135000
```

#### Localhost Logs:

```
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 0
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 7500
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 15000
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 22500
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 30000
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 37500
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 45000
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 52500
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 60000
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 67500
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 75000
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 82500
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 90000
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 97500
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 105000
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 112500
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 120000
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 127500
Memory Usage: 212.76MB INSERT CHUNK 135000
```

Comment: Extensions?  32 vs 64 bit?  Modifications Amazon have made to the PHP runtime?  Libraries included by default by Amazon?  Unless there's somebody who actually works on Amazon's PHP stack here I doubt you'll get a definitive answer

Comment: I've added PHP modules to the list. Both environments are 64 bit. Yeah I'm at a bit of a conundrum on this one. Thankfully this wasn't the biggest problem with the script and I'm able to "deal" with this less than ideal behavior... I'm not holding my breath for a definitive answer but it sparked my curiosity enough to post here to SO and see what the community thought of it.

Comment: Any difference in OS used on the different servers?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix yes drastic differences actually... haha I suppose I should have mentioned that. I am working locally on macOS High Sierra, whereas amazon AWS is on a distribution of CentOS

Comment: I think OPCache might be your culprit there. Try disabling that on the server or enabling locally and see. That caches things to serve pages faster hence more ram needed.

Comment: @samuraiseoul I will definitely try out your suggestion and post back here with updates afterwards. Thanks!

Comment: @samuraiseoul on second thought... this is a batch job that runs via CLI, not through apache & HTTP requests. Isn't OPcache not at play here? Review of php info shows the following: `opcache.enable_cli => Off => Off`

Comment: I would assume that it isn't in play then but perhaps try it both ways to see. That was my only really idea from a cursory look. :S Perhaps there is some really strange difference between 5.6.35 and 5.6.36 in how garbage collection happens? Or how php interacts with the OS or different DB. Can you recreate the AWS instance in a docker container?

Comment: For those finding this question, OPcache was indeed the culprit (or at least poorly tuned OPcache settings).  Check your OPcache status; in our case it was out of memory and therefore nothing was getting cached resulting in huge discrepancies.